# How to separate business logic from JMS listener?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, spring-jms, business-logic

I am writing JmsAdapter where 2 methods named as `sendMessage` for sending messages & `receiveMessage` for receiving message in spring boot, I have one service class `EventService` which uses this JmsAdapter to send message. Now I am confused what to do with message when received in JMSAdapter as i don't want to put any business logic(ex. db call, message processing) in listener `receiveMessage` method. I am doing this to have business logic separated from JMS adapter Here is code for JMSAdapter -

```
public class JmsAdapter {

@Autowired
private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

public void sendMessage(final String jsonMessage) throws JMSException {
    System.out.println("Sending message = " + jsonMessage);
    //TODO replace the queue name based from DB
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("sender", jsonMessage);
    System.out.println("Message Sent");
}

@JmsListener(destination = "${receiver}")
public String receiveMessage(final Message jsonMessage) throws JMSException {
    System.out.println("Received message " + jsonMessage);
    String response = null;
    if(jsonMessage instanceof TextMessage) {
        TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage)jsonMessage;
        response = textMessage.getText();
        System.out.println("Message Received = "+response );
    }
    return response ;
}
```

Do i need to think in different way. What other options are there? As there will be cyclic dependency on Adapter and Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the ideal way is to to separate out the responsibility to send and receive messages. A class having more than one responsibility tends to create these kind of confusions.
If you don't have reservations on using EJBs then a Message Driven Bean can be used to listen to the incoming messages.
If not through EJB then you should have a separate class which is responsible for listening message from this particular queue and process the message. To separate out the responsibility even further, you could call a method(this has all the business logic) implemented in a POJO from your listener.

Comment: But don't you think JmsAdapter should be place for send and receive messages, these are JMS operations and only responsibility to send and receive messages?

Comment: I understand that you are trying to separate out the responsibility of all JMS operations from your business logic but again within the responsibility of your JMS operations, I would suggest you separate out the task of consumer and producer. To give you an analogy - consumer and producer. When you send a message, you are producing one and when you receive a message you are consuming one. I would like a consumer and a producer to be different. I would keep the send in a JMSUtil class and call that and create a <BusinessSpecificPrefix>JMSAdapter to consume the message.

Comment: Yes. Producer and Consumer can again differentiate the JMS functionality. And seeing the only option as of now. Will wait for other inputs as well.

Comment: Hi Swaraj, if the solution worked for you then can you please mark it as an answer ?

Comment: Yes. Going to accept the answer, was expecting some more inputs on this.

Comment: @Preet You have suggested EJB's in 2018 when world is trying to get away with it...???  Am i missing something?